# gcc built-in synchronization functions and cmpxchg

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, locking, mutex

I've trying to implement a lock writing the asm code manually and since the code actually hasn't worked, I used __sync_bool_compare_and_swap to look at the disassembly. 

**However, the built-in function seems not to work too.**

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 x64

Here's the general structure of the program.

**Global:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>

unsigned int randrange(unsigned int min, unsigned int max);   // custom rand function

             pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;   // real mutex
__volatile__ unsigned int    lock = 1;                            // my attempt
             unsigned int    i = 0, count = 0;
```

**Thread function:**

```
void *worker(void *arg)
{
    unsigned int loop = randrange(1000, 10000), time = randrange(10, 100);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);  
    count += loop;                  // safe keep trace of number of iterations
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    /* Acquire the custom lock */

    for(int x = 0; x < loop; x++)
    {
        i++;                // increment i by number of iterations with a step=1
        usleep(time);       // short nap
    }

    __sync_synchronize();   // built-in full barriers
    lock = 1;               // release the custom lock

    pthread_exit((void*) true);
}
```

**Main:**

```
int main()
{
    pthread_t       thread_id[1000];
    pthread_attr_t  attr;
    unsigned int    ret_thread = NULL;
    void           *status = NULL;
    unsigned int    args = NULL;
    unsigned int    nthreads = 1000;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    for(int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++)
    {
        ret_thread = pthread_create(&thread_id[i], &attr, worker,
                                    (void *) &args);
        if(ret_thread)
        {
            printf("Error occurred during thread creation. \
                    n: %i   - return code: %i", i, ret_thread);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

    for(int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++)
    {
        ret_thread = pthread_join(thread_id[i], &status);
        if(ret_thread)
        {
            printf("Error occurred during thread joining. \
                    n: %i   - return code: %i", i, ret_thread);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    puts("\nmain: All the threads exited normally.\n");

    printf("count: %i   -   i: %i\n", count, i);   // core: compare the safe trace or number of iterations with the target one

    puts("\n\nmain: I've finished, bye.\n");

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);

    return 0;
}
```

Since `cmpxchg source, destination` compares the accumulator (register A) with the destination operand, so that

if accumulator == destination then ZF is set and the source is copied into the destination and 

if accumulator != destination then ZF is reset and the destination is copied into the accumulator...

**My attempt:**

```
void *worker(void *arg)
{
    unsigned int loop = randrange(1000, 10000), time = randrange(10, 100);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);  
    count += loop;                  // safe keep trace of number of iterations
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    /* My attempt */

    prepare:
        __asm__ __volatile__      ("xor %r8, %r8");
    wait:
        __asm__ __volatile__      ("nop                        \n\t"
                                   "mov $0x1, %rax             \n\t"
                                   "lock; cmpxchgq %r8, (lock)");
        __asm__ __volatile__ goto ("jne %l0" :::: wait);

    /* My attempt */

    for(int x = 0; x < loop; x++)
    {
        i++;                // increment i by number of iterations with a step=1
        usleep(time);       // short nap
    }

    __sync_synchronize();   // built-in full barriers
    lock = 1;               // release the custom lock

    pthread_exit((void*) true);
}
```

**Disassembly:**

```
(gdb) disas worker
Dump of assembler code for function worker:
   0x0000000000400c70 <+0>:     push   %r12
   0x0000000000400c72 <+2>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400c73 <+3>:     mov    $0x2710,%esi
   0x0000000000400c78 <+8>:     push   %rbx
   0x0000000000400c79 <+9>:     mov    $0x3e8,%edi
   0x0000000000400c7e <+14>:    callq  0x400c20 <randrange>
   0x0000000000400c83 <+19>:    mov    $0x32,%esi
   0x0000000000400c88 <+24>:    mov    $0x1,%edi
   0x0000000000400c8d <+29>:    mov    %eax,%ebp
   0x0000000000400c8f <+31>:    callq  0x400c20 <randrange>
   0x0000000000400c94 <+36>:    mov    $0x602100,%edi
   0x0000000000400c99 <+41>:    mov    %eax,%r12d
   0x0000000000400c9c <+44>:    callq  0x4009d0 <pthread_mutex_lock@plt>
   0x0000000000400ca1 <+49>:    mov    $0x602100,%edi
   0x0000000000400ca6 <+54>:    add    %ebp,0x201434(%rip)      # 0x6020e0 <count>
   0x0000000000400cac <+60>:    callq  0x400980 <pthread_mutex_unlock@plt>
   0x0000000000400cb1 <+65>:    nopl   0x0(%rax)
   0x0000000000400cb8 <+72>:    nop
   0x0000000000400cb9 <+73>:    xor    %r8,%r8
   0x0000000000400cbc <+76>:    mov    $0x1,%rax
   0x0000000000400cc3 <+83>:    lock cmpxchg %r8,0x6020b8         # 0x6020b8 <lock>
   0x0000000000400ccd <+93>:    jne    0x400cb8 <worker+72>
   0x0000000000400ccf <+95>:    xor    %ebx,%ebx
   0x0000000000400cd1 <+97>:    test   %ebp,%ebp
   0x0000000000400cd3 <+99>:    je     0x400cee <worker+126>
   0x0000000000400cd5 <+101>:   nopl   (%rax)
   0x0000000000400cd8 <+104>:   mov    %r12d,%edi
   0x0000000000400cdb <+107>:   add    $0x1,%ebx
   0x0000000000400cde <+110>:   addl   $0x1,0x2013ff(%rip)        # 0x6020e4 <i>
   0x0000000000400ce5 <+117>:   callq  0x4009f0 <usleep@plt>
   0x0000000000400cea <+122>:   cmp    %ebp,%ebx
   0x0000000000400cec <+124>:   jne    0x400cd8 <worker+104>
   0x0000000000400cee <+126>:   mov    $0x1,%edi
   0x0000000000400cf3 <+131>:   mfence 
   0x0000000000400cf6 <+134>:   movl   $0x1,0x2013b8(%rip)        # 0x6020b8 <lock>
   0x0000000000400d00 <+144>:   callq  0x400990 <pthread_exit@plt>
End of assembler dump.
```

**With __sync_bool_compare_and_swap():**

```
void *worker(void *arg)
{
    unsigned int loop = randrange(1000, 10000), time = randrange(10, 100);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);  
    count += loop;                  // safe keep trace of number of iterations
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    /* built-in function */

    while(!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&lock, 1, 0))
    {
        while(lock) __asm__ __volatile__ ("nop");
    }

    /* built-in function */

    for(int x = 0; x < loop; x++)
    {
        i++;                // increment i by number of iterations with a step=1
        usleep(time);       // short nap
    }

    __sync_synchronize();   // built-in full barriers
    lock = 1;               // release the custom lock

    pthread_exit((void*) true);
}
```

**Disassembly:**

```
(gdb) disas worker
Dump of assembler code for function worker:
   0x0000000000400c70 <+0>:     push   %r12
   0x0000000000400c72 <+2>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400c73 <+3>:     mov    $0x2710,%esi
   0x0000000000400c78 <+8>:     push   %rbx
   0x0000000000400c79 <+9>:     mov    $0x3e8,%edi
   0x0000000000400c7e <+14>:    callq  0x400c20 <randrange>
   0x0000000000400c83 <+19>:    mov    $0x32,%esi
   0x0000000000400c88 <+24>:    mov    $0x1,%edi
   0x0000000000400c8d <+29>:    mov    %eax,%ebx
   0x0000000000400c8f <+31>:    callq  0x400c20 <randrange>
   0x0000000000400c94 <+36>:    mov    $0x602100,%edi
   0x0000000000400c99 <+41>:    mov    %eax,%ebp
   0x0000000000400c9b <+43>:    callq  0x4009d0 <pthread_mutex_lock@plt>
   0x0000000000400ca0 <+48>:    mov    $0x602100,%edi
   0x0000000000400ca5 <+53>:    add    %ebx,0x201435(%rip)        # 0x6020e0 <count>
   0x0000000000400cab <+59>:    callq  0x400980 <pthread_mutex_unlock@plt>
   0x0000000000400cb0 <+64>:    mov    $0x1,%ecx
   0x0000000000400cb5 <+69>:    xor    %edx,%edx
   0x0000000000400cb7 <+71>:    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x0000000000400cc0 <+80>:    mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x0000000000400cc2 <+82>:    lock cmpxchg %edx,0x2013ee(%rip)      # 0x6020b8 <lock>
   0x0000000000400cca <+90>:    je     0x400cdd <worker+109>
   0x0000000000400ccc <+92>:    nopl   0x0(%rax)
   0x0000000000400cd0 <+96>:    mov    0x2013e2(%rip),%eax        # 0x6020b8 <lock>
   0x0000000000400cd6 <+102>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000400cd8 <+104>:   je     0x400cc0 <worker+80>
   0x0000000000400cda <+106>:   nop
   0x0000000000400cdb <+107>:   jmp    0x400cd0 <worker+96>
   0x0000000000400cdd <+109>:   xor    %r12d,%r12d
   0x0000000000400ce0 <+112>:   test   %ebx,%ebx
   0x0000000000400ce2 <+114>:   je     0x400cfb <worker+139>
   0x0000000000400ce4 <+116>:   mov    %ebp,%edi
   0x0000000000400ce6 <+118>:   add    $0x1,%r12d
   0x0000000000400cea <+122>:   addl   $0x1,0x2013f3(%rip)        # 0x6020e4 <i>
   0x0000000000400cf1 <+129>:   callq  0x4009f0 <usleep@plt>
   0x0000000000400cf6 <+134>:   cmp    %ebx,%r12d
   0x0000000000400cf9 <+137>:   jne    0x400ce4 <worker+116>
   0x0000000000400cfb <+139>:   mov    $0x1,%edi
   0x0000000000400d00 <+144>:   mfence 
   0x0000000000400d03 <+147>:   movl   $0x1,0x2013ab(%rip)        # 0x6020b8 <lock>
   0x0000000000400d0d <+157>:   callq  0x400990 <pthread_exit@plt>
End of assembler dump.
```

The built-in function produce more code:

```
   0x0000000000400cb0 <+64>:    mov    $0x1,%ecx
   0x0000000000400cb5 <+69>:    xor    %edx,%edx
   0x0000000000400cb7 <+71>:    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x0000000000400cc0 <+80>:    mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x0000000000400cc2 <+82>:    lock cmpxchg %edx,0x2013ee(%rip)  # 0x6020b8 <lock>
   0x0000000000400cca <+90>:    je     0x400cdd <worker+109>
   0x0000000000400ccc <+92>:    nopl   0x0(%rax)
   0x0000000000400cd0 <+96>:    mov    0x2013e2(%rip),%eax        # 0x6020b8 <lock>
   0x0000000000400cd6 <+102>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000400cd8 <+104>:   je     0x400cc0 <worker+80>
   0x0000000000400cda <+106>:   nop
   0x0000000000400cdb <+107>:   jmp    0x400cd0 <worker+96>
```

What does the code between line **96** and **107** do?

I don't think the built-in function produce useless code, so I'd want to understand what I though in the wrong way.

The built-in function it works sometimes which means that it doesn't work at all!

**UPDATE:**

I've retested the implementation with the builtin and it works.

How should I procede?

Comment: No, `test eax, eax`  1) does not change eax at all and 2) only produces zero flag iff eax is zero. `96-107` is your `while(lock) nop`

Comment: @Jester I don't think it's the while loop, because `mov (lock), %eax` and `test %eax, %eax` is a different condition, while the ! __sync(...) should produce `jne wait` or `test %eax, %eax`, testing %eax directly after cmpxchg, but not after have assigned it a new value.

Comment: It is that while loop, but rewritten so that it jumps out of the loop if `lock == 0`. `mov lock, eax; test eax, eax; je` is an `if (lock == 0) break;` The `while(!__sync)` is at lines `82-90`.

Comment: @Jester _"In the x86 assembly language, the TEST instruction performs a bitwise AND on two operands. The flags SF, ZF, PF are modified while the result of the AND is discarded. The OF and CF flags are set to 0, while AF flag is undefined. The TEST operation sets the flags CF and OF to zero. The SF is set to the most significant bit of the result of the AND. If the result of the AND is 0, the ZF is set to 1, otherwise set to 0. The parity flag is set to the bitwise XNOR of the result of the AND. The value of AF is undefined."_ - from (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TEST_%28x86_instruction%29)

Comment: I know what `test` does, you don't seem to :) As your quote says, it performs a bitwise AND with the **result discarded** so, as I said, `eax` is not changed. Also `x AND x` will only give zero if `x` itself is zero which is also what I said. Problem?

Comment: @Jester Why it's necessary? If while(! __sync(...)) continues the loop doesn't it mean that lock wasn't 1, so was equal to 0, in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106473/discussion-between-jumpalways-and-jester).

Comment: Don't use gcc extensions if there are standard compliant alternatives. C provides atomics.

Comment: @Olaf I've only found C++ atomics, but no C atomics...

Comment: In C11, `#include <stdatomic.h>`.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic.  (yes, cppreference.com has a C section, that's *not* a C++ link).  In your inline asm, you could get gcc to supply those values in registers for you.  But of course, it would be better to just use the C11 atomics and not write inline asm at all.

Comment: Also, holy crap you have a global variable called `i`?  Don't do that; everyone reading C expects `i` to be a local loop variable.

Comment: @JumpAlways: Just see the standard! A simple search would have shown also some links.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Why that? global variables are single-letter, locals something like `loop_counter_for_a_deeply_nested_loop_level_8`. So you tell me now that is not common practice?

Comment: @Olaf: Using single-letter globals is definitely not normal in most code-bases.  I tried to google for a reference, instead of trying to explain it myself.  [This looks pretty sensible](http://www.oualline.com/books.free/style/c03.html#pgfId=766).  *The variable named `i` is frequently used as a general purpose, handy dandy, local index.*  That's definitely the convention in C.  There's no need to use such a short non-descriptive name for a global, esp. one that will be shadowed by `for(int i=0; i < MAX ; i++)` in many places.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Try compiling with `#define HUMOR 1` ;-)

Comment: "How should I procede?" - I don't understand.  You have 'working' code using builtins and you are asking how you should proceed?  I assume most answers are going to be "Use the working code."  Perhaps you should clarify exactly what you want to know.